# Multiple filtering in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, filter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I added a filter to my project that works with symfony.

I have the ID (numbers to be searched) and the client name.
When I constructed my query with one parameter, it works, just like that

```
public function findFilter($filter)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
            ->andWhere('a.id like :id')
            ->setParameter('id', '%' . $filter . '%')
            ->getQuery()
            ;
    }
```

and when I add one more parameter, the search doesn't happen.

```
public function findFilter($filter)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
            ->andWhere('a.id like :id')
            ->setParameter('id', '%' . $filter . '%')
            ->andWhere('a.client like :client')
            ->setParameter('client', '%' . $filter . '%')
            ->getQuery()
            ;
    }
```

and here is my view where the filter can be entered

```
<form action="" method="get">
        <input name="filter" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filtrer</button>
 </form>
```

So maybe I'm not sticking them right?
Anyone got an idea on how to add more parameters for the filter bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter on multiple columns with an unique value, you've to use an array of `OR` filters.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;

[...]

$orX = new Expr\Orx(); 
$orX->add($qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('a.id', ':filter'));
$orX->add($qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('a.client', ':filter'));

$qb
    ->andWhere($orx)
    ->setParameter('filter', '%'.$filter.'%')
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
   return $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
        ->andWhere('a.id like :id' OR 'a.client like :client')
        ->setParameters([
             'id' => '%' . $filter . '%',
             'client' => '%' . $filter . '%'
        ]),
        ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found with the expression that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `orWhere` instead of `andWhere`

```
public function findFilter($filter)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
        ->where('a.id like :filter')
        ->orWhere('a.client like :filter')
        ->setParameter('filter', '%' . $filter . '%')
        ->getQuery()
    ;
}
```

Moreover you might have missed a `getResult` after `getQuery` (but don't know if it is a typo or something else)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found a better result with query expression

Comment: @chickenburger no problem. I just wanted to comment this out - for people who'll read this - that  there is absolute no difference between this answer and the accepted one. Both work. Accepted one is less readable imho but it's ok. Just wanted to point out that both are acceptable ;)